# How to add a dynamic marker to a BIRT chart

Tags: charts, birt

I have created a BIRT report with a chart which gets data from a oracle database.
I got the chart done properly. Now i need to add 4-5 markers to the chart. 
Values for markers which could be changed are also stored in a database.

I tried the scripts mentioned in this article with some modifications http://blogs.actuate.com/birt-chart-scripting-dynamic-markers/

```
function beforeGeneration(chart, icsc)
{ 
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.component.impl); 
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.data.impl); 
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.attribute); 
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.attribute.impl);

var chart = icsc.getChartInstance();
var yAxis = chart.getBaseAxes()[0];

var min_value = icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getPersistentGlobalVariable("min_val");
var ok_value = icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getPersistentGlobalVariable("ok_val");
var great_value = icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getPersistentGlobalVariable("great_val");

min_ml = MarkerLineImpl.create(yAxis, NumberDataElementImpl.create(min_value));
min_ml.getLabel().getCaption().setValue("Minimum");
min_ml.getLineAttributes().getColor().set(255,0,0);

}
```

It generates a marker but at the wrong location.
Seems like it doesn't properly get marked according to the x axis values.

[image]

What could be the issue in this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue with the script.

I tried giving a hard coded value to the min_value then it worked. After debugging i found out that the data format of the X axis was with decimals which didn't match with the integer format value taken from the database.

From the format chart window i changed the axis data format to a number with 0 decimals.Then it worked :)

Comment: http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/36669-how-to-add-a-dynamic-marker-to-a-birt-chart/